# How does this work regarding UI thread

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

In the AppCompatActivity just wanted to get some feedback on this. When does this Runnable run?

Is the `super.onBackPressed();` posted on Main ui thread and then my Runnable is also posted to Main ui thread? which I know is a queue right. is this correct?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             // some work
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: code in onBackPressed always will run on UI thread..

Comment: It's a thread, not a que perse.

If you want to access anything in the UI it's required to run things on UI like that. However as you said before it's already on the UI thread because onBackPressed is called from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed()` will always be called on `UI thread`. so `runOnUiThread()` method is unnecessary here.

What your code does is post the `Runnable` on the UI thread from UI thread itself

Internally `runOnUiThread()` does the below action

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: My Q is not so clear but I experience that if I press back button on a Fragment and in the `public void onBackPressed() ` I want to get the current Fragment that now is in `R.id.frame` after `super.onBackPressed();` I have to run this:  `FragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame);` inside the` runOnUiThread`

Comment: `onBackPressed()` will be called only on `Activity` on the `UI thread` so you can run you code without `runOnUiThread()`